# Returning a value in one file and using it in another

Tags: python

I'm trying to use return to get a value but it "disappears" between two files...

This is where it's "created". The prints work, so it registers the clicks, but True is somehow not returned?

```
def check_mouseclicks(self):
    """Checks if buttons are clicked"""

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.new_game_nrect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                print("new game")
                return True
            elif self.cont_nrect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                print("continue")
                return True
            elif self.quit_nrect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                sys.exit()
```

This is where I need it:

```
        self.menu = Menu(self.screen)
        self.gamestate_active = self.menu.check_mouseclicks()
        print(self.gamestate_active)
        if self.gamestate_active:
            pass
```

the print results in "None"

I tried googling it, finding a lot on here already but I can't find my mistake. Showed it to a friend... Nothing :(

EDIT:

Tried

```
if self.menu.check_mouseclicks():
    print("hi")
```

Tried returning

```
key = 1 
return key
```

-->

```
key = self.menu.check_mouseclicks()
if key == 1:
    print("hi")
```

This did not change anything.

Comment: If you don't explicitly return anything it will return `None`, in this case if there is no event in that exact frame it will return `None`

Comment: @mousetail so should I make use of the returned true in the "if"?
would 

`if self.menu.check_mouseclicks():

    ...`

work?

EDIT: not the solution, no print, no error

Comment: @CmdLari Within your check_mouseclicks function, after the for loop has run for all events, add `return False`.  What you're seeing is that either none of the events are `QUIT` or `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` or the event `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` is found, but none of the collision checks return `True`.